# Can't enable Virtual Machine Platform for WSL using DISM

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dism

To enable WSL 2, I try to run `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`, but an error occurs:

[image: Screenshot]

> Error: 1168
>
> Element not found.

this is my dism.log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b7FEqS4TibXWovvC4koovqFurnKOJh75/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We need more information than a screenshot of an error pointing to a log file.

Comment: Have you tried simply opening "Windows Features" and checking the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" checkbox or are you needing to automate this process?

Comment: Please make sure to accurately ask your question. Also include any relevant messages as text, not just as a screenshot. I fixed it up for now.

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt as administrator and type: `wsl --install`

you can also check the list of disto that you can install: `wsl --list --online`

and if you want to choose a specific distro use: `wsl --install -d distroname`
an example would be: `wsl --install -d Ubuntu`

you can also check the status of wsl: `wsl --status`

Comment: not work because the virtual machine feature isn't turning on